# laravel 5.5 register and login of multi user on one table

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5, multi-user

after following the tutorials given by DevMarketer, i want to know how to create a login/registration form of all my users using only 'one table'.

Answer (score 1):

As already highlighted by Marcus, you can run `php artisan make:auth` command to scaffold authentication. It is recommended to run this command on freshly installed Laravel.

You want authentication for multiple users. What I understand from multiple users is you want it to work with different types of users e.g. Users can be customers and users can be Admins.

For this you can make a new column on the users table. For doing this, you can simple edit the user table migration if you haven't already migrated it otherwise you can make new migration.

You can check if user has access to some specific pages, [Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) can be used for this.

I forgot to tell, you can also use [Laravel Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) to authorize a user for specific task.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan make:auth` creates a login and registration form  including database table

Then run the migrate command